# Stack Overflow Worldwide Meetups 2012: You're invited!

Tags: discussion, community

We're having a Stack Overflow meetup to get together with fellow programming, web, and other technology enthusiasts. But not all of our programmers and technology enthusiasts live on Stack Overflow, so this year we're explicitly expanding the Meetup Everywhere to include the whole Stack Exchange tech family. As a Sharepoint participant, you're invited, too!

We [recently announced](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) the Second Annual Stack Overflow Meetup Everywhere day. This year, it will be on Saturday, April 28 (though local groups are welcome to pick any other day that week if a Saturday doesn't work for most of your members).

**What:** Stack Overflow worldwide meetups

**When:** Saturday, April 28, 2012

**Where:** your city!

**Who:** All users on Stack Exchange technology sites

You can visit the [official Meetup.com page](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/) to find existing groups near you (or start a new one). Keep an eye on the Stack Exchange blog for more information as we move closer to the event - I'll post tips on what we learned from last year's event and some things to keep in mind when organizing your local meetup. See the [blog announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) for some ideas about what your meetup can look like, why we're doing this, and some help navigating the meetup.com interface.

We'd love to see as many of you as possible participate in our Meetup Everywhere. We had over 2,000 people meet up around the world last year, and we've grown a lot since then. Help us spread the word by sharing info about this event through your blogs, social media accounts, lunches with coworkers, etc.

As always, if you have any questions or comments, do not hesitate to get in touch, and I hope to see you there!

Comment: Woohoo! I RSVP'd for the St. Louis one. Not sure if anyone else on here is nearby...